# Find the probability that atleast one valve is defective.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A factory A produces $10$% defective valves and another factory $B$ produces 20% defective valves.A bag contains $4$ valves of factory $A$ and $5$ valves of factory B.If two valves are drawn at random from the bag,find the probability that at least one valve is defective.

---

$P(\text{at least one valve is defective})=\\=1-P(\text{none of the two valves are defective})=\\=1-\left(\frac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{9}{2}}(0.9)^2+\frac{\binom{5}{2}}{\binom{9}{2}}(0.8)^2+\frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{1}}{\binom{9}{2}}(0.9)(0.8)\right)=\frac{517}{1800}$,

but the answer given is $\frac{303}{1800}$ I don't know where i am wrong.

Comment: You are correct. The given answer is wrong.

Comment: This question confuses me as well. In fact, if you try to find the answer using  5 mutually exclusive case : 1. Both valves are from fact A. (both are defective).2. Both from B. 3)One defective from each. 4) one defective from A and non defective  from B 5)One defective from B and non defective from A and add these probabilities, the answer comes out to be $303/1800$. I also wonder why? Can it be that there is some problem in calculation of both valves are non defective case as they may not be independent events. Please let me know if you already know the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Probability that factory $A$ produces defective values is $\dfrac{10}{100}=\dfrac{1}{10}$

The Probability that factory $B$ produces defective values is $\dfrac{20}{100}=\dfrac{1}{5}$

Given a bag contains $4$ values of factory $A$ and $5$ values of factory $B$ and two values are drawn random.

$$P(\mbox{at least one defective})=1-P(\mbox{both are non-defective})$$
$$P(\mbox{both are non-defective})=P(\mbox{both values of factory }B)\times P(\mbox{both are non-defective})+P(\mbox{both values of factory }B)\times P(\mbox{ both are non defective})+P(\mbox{one value of $A$ and other of factory $B$})\times P(\mbox{both are nondefective})$$
$$=\dfrac{\dbinom{4}{2}}{\dbinom{9}{2}}\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^2+\dfrac{\dbinom{5}{2}}{\dbinom{9}{2}}\left(\dfrac45\right)^2+\dfrac{\dbinom{4}{1}\cdot\binom{5}{1}}{\binom{9}{2}}\times\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)\times\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)$$
$$=\dfrac{27}{200}+\dfrac{8}{45}+\dfrac{2}{5}=\dfrac{1283}{1800}$$
Now, $P(\mbox{at least one defective})=1-\dfrac{1283}{1800}=\approx0.29$

So, the answer what you got is $\dfrac{517}{1800}\approx0.29$ which is correct.

Comment: It seems correct. But if we consider 5 mutually exclusive case : 1. Both valves are from fact A. (both are defective).2. Both from B. 3)One defective from each. 4) one defective from A and non defective  from B 5)One defective from B and non defective from A. If we add these probabilities, the answer comes out to be $303/1800$. I also wonder why? Can it be that there is some problem in calculation of both valves are non defective case as they may not be independent events. Please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is indeed $\frac{517}{1800}$, because:

$$P(\text{at least one of two defective})=1-P(\text{both normal})=\\
1-[P(ANAN)+P(ANBN)+P(BNAN)+P(BNBN)]=\\
1-\left[\frac{4}{9}\cdot \frac9{10}\cdot \frac38\cdot \frac9{10}+
\frac{4}{9}\cdot \frac9{10}\cdot \frac58\cdot \frac8{10}+
\frac{5}{9}\cdot \frac8{10}\cdot \frac48\cdot \frac9{10}+
\frac{5}{9}\cdot \frac8{10}\cdot \frac48\cdot \frac8{10}\right]=\\
1-\frac{1283}{1800}=\frac{517}{1800}.$$