# Find the probability that at least one valve is defective when two valves are drawn at random.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification

> **Problem Statement:**

- A factory A produces $10\ \%$ defective valves
- and another factory $B$ produces $\mbox{$20\ \%$}$ defective valves.
- A bag contains $4$ valves of factory $A$
  and $5$ valves of factory B.
- If two valves are drawn at random from the
  bag, find the probability that *at least* one valve is defective.

This question has been asked here once.
[Find the probability that atleast one valve is defective.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2857533/find-the-probability-that-atleast-one-valve-is-defective)

Now, clearly Probability of drawing atleast one defective valve)=1- Probability that both valves drawn are non-defective valves 
Using this, the required probability is
$
=1-\left(\frac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{9}{2}}(0.9)^2+\frac{\binom{5}{2}}{\binom{9}{2}}(0.8)^2+\frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{1}}{\binom{9}{2}}(0.9)(0.8)\right)=\frac{517}{1800},
\label{1}\tag{1}
$
as OP has also shown in the above linked post.

However, this is where the confusion arises: 
**Alternatively,** let's consider the following mutually exclusive events:

1. Both valves are defective and are from factory $A$
2. Both valves are defective and are from factory $B$
3. Both valves are defective (one from $A$ and the other from $B$)
4. One valve is drawn from $A$ and is defective while the other is drawn from $B$ and is non-defective.
5. One valve is drawn from $B$ and is defective while the other is drawn from $A$ and is non-defective.

Now the required probability = Sum of all the probabilities of mutually exclusive events listed above.

Let's denote probability for the ith event listed above by $P(i)$, where $i=1,2,3,4,5$ 
$P(1)=\frac{^4C_2}{^9C_2}(0.1)^2\;\;,P(2)=\frac{^5C_2}{^9C_2}(0.2)^2\;\;,P(3)=\frac{^4C_1 \times ^5C_1}{^9C_2}(0.1)(0.2)\;\;$ 
$P(4)=\frac{^4C_1\times ^5C_1}{^9C_2}(0.1)(0.8)\;\; ,P(5)=\frac{^4C_1 \times ^5C_1}{^9C_2}(0.9)(0.2)\;\;$ 
Therefore, the required probability is $$P=\sum_{i=1}^{5}P(i)=1/600+1/90+1/90+2/45+1/10=303/1800
\label{2}\tag{2}$$

**I want to know why answers in (\ref{1}) and (\ref{2}) above are different**. In fact, in the link above, OP had mentioned that answer given in his book was $303/1800$, whereas the comments and answers to that post mentioned the answer as wrong. But $(2)$ clearly shows that there is nothing wrong with the answer. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from two cases that you are missing:

- Both valves are drawn from $A$ and exactly one is defective
- Both valves are drawn from $B$ and exactly one is defective

The probability of one of those events occurring is
$$
\frac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{9}{2}} \times 0.1 \times 0.9 \times 2
+
\frac{\binom{5}{2}}{\binom{9}{2}} \times 0.2 \times 0.8 \times 2
= \frac{54+160}{1800} = \frac{214}{1800} = \frac{517}{1800} - \frac{303}{1800}
\,.$$

OP's answer is correct.

Comment: Will you please have a look at my other question also on probability? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3795589/doubt-on-a-probability-question-finding-the-probability-of-a-man-to-die-next-ye

Comment: Looks like somebody else got to it before me :)